# Reset (nullify) Laravel/Eloquent connection

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

I'm using Lumen and Eloquent for the first time to build an API. I need to query the same table across several databases in one request. The algo I'm using is as follows:

```
foreach($db in $dbs) {
   config(['database.connections.clientdb.database' => $db]); 
   $count = MyModel->all()->count()
   $myArray[] = $count
}
```

Instead of getting an array of different values, the values are always the same; the value generated from the first database connection.

Since the first database is not the configured database, I know the `config` command works (at least once). I verified that the database name does change on each iteration. I'm not (knowingly) using a cache. I used the `$mymodel = new MyModel('$db')` and executing the model's `setConnection()` in the constructor then setting `$mymodel = null`. The value of `$count` never changes.

I'm *guessing* the database connection isn't being released. How do I get Lumen/Laravel/Eloquent to tear down the database connection and connect to another one inside the same request?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the help of [this posting](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/repository-model-with-multiple-database).

The basic idea is that you do not (cannot?) override a configuration. Instead, you create a new configuration on the fly and (to make life easy on yourself) set it as the default database connection.

Comment: This still apply today? Any tips on this after 4 years?

Comment: Nothing new on my end. Once I get something working (with an understanding how it works) I move on. I don't even remember the project! :-)